# What are viewproviders in Angular? And what is the difference b/w providers vs viewproviders?

Tags: angular

What is viewProviders in the below code? And how it differs from providers?

```ts
class Greeter {
   greet(name:string) {
     return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
   }
}    
@Component({
  selector: 'greet',
  viewProviders: [
    Greeter
  ],
  template: `<needs-greeter></needs-greeter>`    
})
class HelloWorld {
}
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

In your example, there is no difference between providers and viewProviders because HelloWorld's template doesn't use `<ng-content>`.  If you were projecting content within `<ng-content>...</ng-content>`, then Greeter couldn't be injected in the projected content because you're using

```
viewProviders: [Greeter]
```

If you wanted Greeter to potentially be injected into the projected content, you'd use

```
providers: [Greeter]
```

So `viewProviders` limits the provider to children other than projected content, while `providers` allows all children to use the provider.  The value is that `viewProviders` allows you to prevent projected content from messing with your services, which could be especially useful in libraries.

Comment: To understand this answer , first we should understand what is the difference between view child and content(projected) child;

Comment: So it's just badly named ;-) It should be `thisProviders` or `myProviders` or `selfProviders` or .... OK those are all worse!

Comment: @Mark I'm still confused about this. Isn't projected content effectively 'owned' by the parent control. So it has to have been created by the parent control. Therefore how could something from the ultimate host of that projected content provide anything to it because it would have already been created. What am I missing? Does it really 'hoist' up the providers for the ultimate end host?

Answer (score 43):

1. If we want to share one instance of a service across the entirety of our application we configure it in providers on our NgModule.
2. If we want to have one instance of a service per component, and shared with all the component’s children,  we configure it on the providers property on our component decorator. Child is a view children.
3. If we want to have one instance of a service per component, and shared with only the component’s view children and not the component’s content children,  we configure it on the viewProviders property of our component decorator.

Comment: single and elegant to understand

Answer (score 5):

share one instance of a service across the entire application
-> configure it in providers of root module [AppModule]

share one instance of a service across the entire Module
-> configure it in providers of that module

share one instance of a service across the entire Component
-> configure it in providers of that Component

share one instance of a service across Component [only ViewChildren not ContentChildren]
-> configure it in viewProviders of that Component

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the required scope of service:

- **Module-wide single instance of Service**: use `providers:[Service]` in @NgModule decorator
- **Component-wide single instance of service**: use `providers:[Service]` in @Component decorator. This instance of service will be shared with both **ContentChildren** & **ViewChildren** of that component

> **ContentChildren**: Child components which are projected into a component using content-projection i.e. `<ng-content></ng-content>`
>
> **ViewChildren**: Child components which are defined inside the component's template and are not projected.

- **Component-wide single instance of service excluding ContentChildren**:
  use `viewProviders: [Service]` in @Component decorator

Answer (score 2):

A bit off topic, but I want to make a correction to some of the answers, stating that services provided in @NgModule are singletons available to the entire scope of the application. You may run into cases, where that is not true.

Services do not live in modules, they live in injectors. At the very top level Angular has the Null Injector, below that is the Platform Injector and below that, sits the Root Injector. Platform and Root are Module injectors. **Weather services, provided in modules, are in the root injector, depends if the modules are eagerly loaded, or not**. Services provided in eagerly loaded modules are created in the Root Injector, so in those cases, providing the service in an @NgModule, will make the service a singleton in the root injector. For lazily loaded modules however, angular creates more Module injectors (1 injector for every lazily loaded module), which is below the root injector [from docs](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#:%7E:text=Child%20ModuleInjector%20hierarchies%20are%20created%20when%20lazy%20loading%20other%20%40NgModules.). In that case providing the service in the @NgModule will not give you a singleton service available to the entire scope of the application, but rather a service, which will be available to the children of the lazily loaded module.

To avoid thinking about this (for angular 6+), if you want a singleton for your entire app, you can tell angular, you want the service in your root injector in the service class itself:

```
@Injectable({
   provideIn: 'root'
})
class MyService...
```

This will ensure the service is available in angular's root injector

Answer (score 0):

Given the [documentation](https://angular.dev/guide/di/hierarchical-dependency-injection#providers-vs-viewproviders)

> The viewProviders field is conceptually similar to providers, but there is one notable difference. Configured providers in viewProviders are not visible to projected content that ends up as a logical children of the component.

Let's declare a dummy service

```
export class DummyService {
  name = 'Dummy';
}
```

with some components

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AComponent, BComponent],
  template: `
  <app-a>
    <app-b></app-b>
  </app-a>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  viewProviders: [DummyService],
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class AComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}`
})
export class BComponent {
  dummyService = inject(DummyService); // ERROR No provider for DummyService! 
}
```

`BComponent` cannot find provider for `DummyService` because its declared inside the `ComponentA` viewProviders which is not visible to its projected content (i.e. `ng-content`).

Using `providers` instead of `viewProviders` would work perfectly

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [DummyService],
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class AComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}` // Dummy
})
export class BComponent {
  dummyService = inject(DummyService);
}
```

We can also use `viewProviders` and declare `BComponent` as a child of `AComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AComponent],
  template: `<app-a></app-a>`,
})
export class AppComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BComponent],
  viewProviders: [DummyService],
  template: `<app-b></app-b>`,
})
export class AComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}`, // Dummy
})
export class BComponent {
  dummyService = inject(DummyService);
}
```

Last but not least, there's also a difference when using `host` injection option (or `@Host()` parameter decorator)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BComponent],
  providers: [DummyService],
  template: `<app-b></app-b>`,
})
export class AComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}`,
})
export class BComponent {
  dummyService = inject(DummyService, {host: true});
  // ERROR : No provider for DummyService found
}
```

`BComponent` cannot inject `DummyService` because its not provided into its `Host` (i.e. `BComponent` itself)

However, using `viewProviders` instead of `providers` would resolve the error

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BComponent],
  viewProviders: [DummyService],
  template: `<app-b></app-b>`,
})
export class AComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: `{{ dummyService.name }}` // Dummy
})
export class BComponent {
  dummyService = inject(DummyService, {host: true});
}
```

This is because services declared in `viewProviders` are visible to the view dom children, so in this example, it means `DummyService` is provided to the child `ComponentB`.

Note that `dummyService` can of course be injected into `ComponentA` (it's not only provided to its view children but also to the component itself).