# Angular 2: contentChildren communication

Tags: angular, angular2-template

What is the preferred method of communicating between contentChildren and its 'parent'?

**UPDATED: Child may not be direct parent...**

Given a random list of children, wrapped by a group:

```
<child-group>
    <div>Some other content, child may not be direct parent...</div>
    <child *ngFor="let item of data$ | async;"></child>
</child-group>
```

The child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<button (click)="didSomethingTellGroup()"></button>',
    styleUrls: ['child.component.scss'],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log('Called from group component')
    }

    didSomethingTellGroup() {
        //EventEmitter?
        //Observable?
    }

}
```

The parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-group',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
    styleUrls: ['child-group.component.scss'],
})
export class ChildGroupComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(ChildComponent) childrenList: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        //How to invoke doSomething() on all children?
        childrenList...

        //How can I get notification from one or all children, that it did something, or its state has changed.
        childrenList...
    }
}
```

How can I invoke a child method from ChildGroup? And how can a Child send information back to the ChildGroup?

**UPDATE:**

In the comments below I mentioned that when I was trying to invoke a method on the children nothing was happening. Well it turns out that I needed subscribe to the changes and wait for the children...then I was able to invoke

```
ngAfterContentInit()
{
    this.childrenList.changes
        .subscribe(list => {
                list.forEach(c => c.doSomething())
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: you can create a function on child which you can call looping on childrenList, similarly you can create a eventemitter which you may subscribe in the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answers are totally correct, using `@Output` and looping through your `QueryList` is the way to go, but if, as you mentioned, your children are not direct ones, you could use a service as a communication chanel.

Here is a very basic plunker demonstrating this: http://plnkr.co/edit/VuYiz7gVB42PEnnk2d8C (I'm not an expert at observables so maybe this could be improved).

Basically, when you click on a button of your child component, it uses:

```
this.myService.sendToParent(this.random);
```

To send a message to the parent through the service. In this function, the service sends a message through an observable to the parent:

```
this.parentSubject.next(value);
```

Previously, the parent subscribed to this observable:

```
this.service.getParentMessages().subscribe((data) =>
{
  alert('Something changed from a children: ' + data);

  this.service.sendToChildren(data);
});
```

As you can see, when it receives a new value, it uses the function `sendToChildren` to send a message to all his children through the service (the same principle apply then). When children receive messages, it changes a value that is finally displayed in the component.

Comment: Thank-you for the elaborate reply. How could I ensure that the service used is unique for the specific group? Is this where viewProvider would come in?

Comment: I edited my plunker to show you how to do this. Basically, instead of importing the provider in the app module, I imported it in the parent component, this way, a new instance of the service is created for each component of that type. For more information, see this awesome answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888434/what-are-viewproviders-in-angular-2-and-what-is-the-difference-b-w-providers-vs

Comment: maybe I should start a new question for this, but when I moved the provider in the parent I got this error: Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for MyService! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then - I did bump up to Angular 4 today, not sure if there is a difference there. But, in my app I am using lazy loading and this parent/child is part of a module, I am only importing it in the parent component, this is indeed the only place I need to import it? Not sure where I am going wrong... thanks

Comment: As you said, it is better to create a new issue with a plumber if possible

Comment: I will for that issue, merci. But if you can please clarify one thing. It now appears that I need to nest these 'child-groups'. It is unclear to me when I tried that with your plunker how or if nested groups were sharing unique instances of the service, or if it was from the parent 'child-group'..? Thanks again

Comment: You mean that you chould have a `child-group` inside a `child-group`?

Comment: Could you please create a new issue for this (as your initial question has been answered). Thanks

Comment: sure thing, will do later. Thanks for your time appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

For your child to parent scenario, an @Output event emitter is your best bet. Your child component is converting an internal action in itself ( a user clicking somewhere) into a business related event that any user of that component can listen for.

As for parent calling child, you're already most of the way there with your example. Just iterate over the QueryList and call whatever method you wish on your child components.

```
ngAfterContentInit() {    
  //How to invoke     doSomething() on all children?  
  this.childrenList.forEach ( c => c.doSomething(); ) 
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have forgot to show that the child may or may not be direct parent, would @Ouput still work? I'll update my question..

Comment: If it's not a direct child, then no, you have to either bubble the event up the chain manually, or use a service to broker the communication

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried invoking callMethod(), but nothing happens. Logging out this.childrenList.length results in 0..

For the service, how could I guarantee that the service would be unique to this set of children/Group only, as I can have more than one child-group on the page. Or even nested...

Comment: See my answer (and the comment) above ;-)